# NSInternalInconsistencyException observer contentSize

Tags: swift, uitextview

Getting this error

```
2017-07-28 20:17:34.636 App[78013:1799389] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fa97b0bf400 of class App.MessagesCellTextView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x618000434e80> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x618000243c60: Observer: 0x7fa97b0bf400, Key path: contentSize, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x618000243c90>
```

when i leave the chat controller and go back.

this is my code for contentSize

```
var observerAdded: Bool = false

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"contentSize", options:.new, context:nil)
    observerAdded = true



}

deinit {
    if (observerAdded) {
        observerAdded = false
        self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
    }
}


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let textView = object as? UITextView {

        var y: CGFloat = (textView.bounds.size.height - textView.contentSize.height * textView.zoomScale) / 2.0
        y = (y < 0.0 ? 0.0 : y)

        textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -y)

    }
}
```

weird thing is, i tried removing all of these code but i still get the same error, what!!.

Answer (score 0):

Check the flag if observer is not added inside your `awakeFromnib` method then add it accordingly:-

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
   if !observerAdded {
     self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"contentSize", options:.new, context:nil)
     observerAdded = true
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't work, still crashing, as i said if i remove all the observer key thing, it still crashes. this is very weird